# How to Splice method performance error with max

Tags: javascript, math

I have a dilemma with this line of code

```
let numero = [11,5,7,9,10,12];
console.log(numero.splice(Math.min.aply(null, numero), 1));
console.log(numero);
```

This line of code should eliminate the number 5 which is the smallest of the array, but it eliminates the 12, I have tried in different ways, but I can't get it to eliminate the 5. I have not found the error thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

You found the number, but then you have tried to remove it by itsef instead of by its index, which is what splice was expecting. Try this:

```
numero.splice(numero.indexOf(Math.min(...numero)),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.min` will return the minimum in your array but splice would like to have the **position** of the min value inside your array.
You need to look for the **index(position)** and not for the value itself.
You can use the [.indexOf()](https://github.com/CreaTorAlexander/javascript) method

*Note:* Prefer the use of the spread operator ... to call variadic functions.

Why? It’s cleaner, you don’t need to supply a context, and you can not easily compose new with apply.

```
// bad
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log.apply(console, x);

// good
const x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(...x);

// bad
new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null, 2016, 8, 5]));

// good
new Date(...[2016, 8, 5]);
```

In this [repository](https://github.com/CreaTorAlexander/javascript) you can read more about best practices

```js
let numero = [11, 5, 7, 9, 10, 12];

console.log(numero.splice(numero.indexOf(Math.min(...numero)),1));
```